# DynamoDB filter data with filed using python boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, fastapi

I try to scan the data with the following query:

```
response= table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('userid').eq(userid))
```

but it's not working. I am dropping from aws console data is filtering

[image]

This is my sample code with throws the exception:

```
def get_employee_analytics(self, userid: str):
   try:
        table = self.__db.Table('analytics')
        
        response= table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('userid').eq(userid))
    
        return response['Item']
   except ClientError as e:
        raise ValueError(e.response['Error']['Message'])
```

Comment: What is the complete python code allowing to reproduce the issue?

Comment: am able  to fetch data from key condition, database connection are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Please add more details to your issue, what is the full stack trace of the error?

One issue I see is that you are returning `response['Item']`. This is not correct because you are invoking a multi-item API `Scan` your response will be Items and would look like `response['Items']`

Furthermore, you will need to implement pagination, to ensure you read more than 1MB of data.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-implement-pagination/